# Multiple Error: Cannot assign to value: 'image' is a method, expected ')' list, only instance methods can be declared @IBActions

Tags: xcode

I'm still a beginner in XCode, so please bear with me. I can't figure out the 3 errors stated above, with "Cannot assign to value: 'image" os a method" in line 35, "Expected ')' in expression list in line 58, and "Only instance methods can be declared @IBAction" in lines 58 and 62.

Thank you in advance!

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class UserVC: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var userImagePicker: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var completeSignInBtn: UIButton!

    var userUid: String!
    var emailField: String!
    var passwordField: String!
    var imagePicker : UIImagePickerController!
    var imageSelected = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
            userImagePicker.image = image
            imageSelected = true
        } else {
            print("image wasn't selected")
        }
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func uploadImg() {

    }

    @IBAction func completeAccount(_ sender: Any){
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailField, password: passwordField, completion: { (user,error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        } else {
            if let user = user {
                self.userUid = user.user.uid
            }
        }

    }

        func selectedImagePicker(_ sender: Any){
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

        func cancel(_ sender: AnyObject){
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `func selectedImagePicker(_ sender: Any){...}` & `func cancel(_ sender: AnyObject){...}` are INSIDE `@IBAction func completeAccount(_ sender: Any)`, strange. See the indentation different.

Comment: @Larme thanks for the response. cant seem to work though. even trying to move it and remove the indentation doesn't work

Comment: It’s not about the identation, it’s about the fact that the methods are not in the same level/scope of {}.